# Counting the number of occurrences of a specific value in a text file

Tags: python, text

I have text file with 30 columns. and using python I want to count the number of rows based on the value in column 3. in fact how many times "cement" occurs in column 3. also columns do not have name (or header).

```
count = 0
with open('first_basic.txt') as infile: 
    for line in infile: 
        for j in (line.split()[3]): 
            if j == "cement": 
                count += 1
```

thanks

Comment: I am not programmer. just biologist

Comment: Provide us with the code that you have tried and tell us what it doesn't do that you want it to. Show us your effort and only then can we help you.

Comment: I tried this code but not working>>> count = 0
>>> with open('first_basic.txt') as infile:
...     for line in infile:
...         for j in (line.split()[3]):
...             if j == "cement":
...                 count += 1

Comment: Looks like you might have an off-by-1 bug in there.  If you are referring to the third column, then you should change line.split()[3] to line.split()[2]

Comment: I tried 2. but I got only the first element of 3rd column. yes this is the largest string

Comment: Could you provide an example text file?

Comment: after asking for help, you abandoned you question.  If you had provided a facsimile of your data, this could be easily resolved

Answer (score 0):

You are checking each character of 3rd column (word) of every line, to check if it equals cement:

```
'c' == 'cement' => False
'e' == 'cement' => False
etc.
```

You should replace

```
for j in (line.split()[2]): 
    if j == "cement": 
        count += 1
```

with

```
if line.split()[2] == "cement": 
    count += 1
```

Full code:

```
count = 0
with open('first_basic.txt') as infile: 
    for line in infile: 
        if line.split()[2] == "cement": 
            count += 1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you define a predicate function for your matches:

```
def match(line):
    return line.split()[2] == 'cement'
```

You can use this predicate with a `filter` and calculate the count of matching lines:

```
with open('first_basic.txt') as infile: 
    print(len(list(filter(match, infile.readlines()))))
```

But this requires memory to build the `list` first. Using a generator may be faster and does not require the memory for the list:

```
    print(sum(1 for line in infile if match(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays has the start position as 0 not as 1. So if you want to get the third element of `['DUMMY', 'DUMMY', 'CEMENT', 'NOT_CEMENT']` yoy have to take the `[2]` position. Because the `[3]` position is 'NOT_CEMENT'.

And the seccond for, is taking letter by letter, not row by row. The row you took in line.

So to fix your code change:

```
if line.split()[2] == "cement": #Change here for two
    count += 1
```

But you can take a clean solution for that doing somthing like this:

```
with open('first_basic.txt') as infile: 
    map(lambda x: x.split()[2], infile).count('cement')
```

Let's explain the code.

The `map()` is responsible to do much like the same as for. It will iterates in all elements of an iterable object. And for each element it apply a function.

The function that was used is this:

```
lambda x: x.split()[2]
```

This is a functional way to do this:

```
def function(x):
    return x.split()[2]
```

But why I used lambda? There is a simple answer, I will not call this function anymore. So I don't need to use space in my memory to this function so I used lambda AKA anonymous function in Python.

You can check about map function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and lambda functions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression).

I hope that I helped.